# Spring: Failed to write HTTP message: org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, jackson

I have two entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Order {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(nullable = true)
    private String name;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order",
                cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<Product> products = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addProduct(Product product) {
        products.setOrder(this);
        getProducts().add(product);
    }
}
```

And the second:

```
@Entity
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Product {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = Order.class)
    @JoinColumn(name = "product_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
    private Order order;

}
```

And the controller:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class PersistenceController {

    @Autowired
    private OrderRepository repository;

    @PostConstruct
    private void init() {
        Order order = new Order();
        order.setName("some_order");

        Product product = new Product();
        order.addProduct(product);

        repository.save(order);
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getAll", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @ResponseBody
    List<Order> getAll() {
        return repository.findAll();
    }
}
```

And the exception looks like:

> Failed to write HTTP message:
>   org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotWritableException:
>   Could not write content: Could not set field value [Product(id=1,
>   order=null)] value by reflection
>       : [class model.entities.Product.order] setter of model.entities.Product.order (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0]->model.entities.RoomEntity["products"]); nested
>   exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException:
>   Could not set field value [Product(id=1, day=null, startHour=null,
>   endHour=null,order=null)] value by reflection : [class
>   model.entities.Product.order] setter of model.entities.Product.order
>   (through reference chain:
>   java.util.ArrayList[0]->model.entities.Order["products"]) 2017-04-15
>   17:38:36.073 WARN 18200 --- [nio-8091-exec-1] 
>       o.h.e.loading.internal.LoadContexts : HHH000100: Fail-safe cleanup (collections) :
>   org.hibernate.engine.loading.internal.CollectionLoadContext@3713fa6c
>   2017-04-15 17:38:36.073 WARN 18200 --- [nio-8091-exec-1]
>   o.h.e.l.internal.CollectionLoadContext : HHH000160: On
>   CollectionLoadContext#cleanup, localLoadingCollectionKeys contained
>   [1] entries

Comment: Do you have `Product.setOrder()` (and the corresponding getter)?

Comment: Also, is the the full stack trace?